# Prevent drawing of a specific UICollectionViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need to prevent the drawing of a specific `UICollectionViewCell`.

I have tried to set the cell hide or set `alpha=0` in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method but
unfortunately it remains empty space and my goal is not that.
I have tried also to use the delegate method "sizeForItemAtIndexPath" setting the width and height of my item to ZERO but it interferes on the alignement.

I need that the item remains on the `CollectionView` datasource but not visible in my `CollectionView` grid.

Is it possibile to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you could avoid a lot of bugs if you respect the UICollectionView.

You should stop tricking the UICollectionView. If it is hidden, it shouldn't be on the UICollectionView.

You can create a layer that encapsulates your dataSource structure and returns only what you want to display in your CollectionView. Imagine that you have some sort of filter. You could have something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* collectionViewData;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray* collectionViewDataSource;
```

Then you override your collectionViewDataSource getter:

```
- (NSArray*) collectionViewDataSource {
   if(self.filterIsOn) {
       NSMutableArray* filteredData = [self.collectionViewData mutableCopy];

       //remove the cells you don't want to show. 
       //I HATE THAT LAST OBJECT
       [filteredData removeLastObject];
       return [filteredData copy];
   } 

   return self.collectionViewData;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tiago, it's a nice idea, if I will decide I will not use a custom layout to filter cells, I will use your method.